# How to update the existing cookies in asp.net through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I have tried to update the existing cookies like this:

```
        CityID = opt.attr('id');
```

where CityID is a cookies name. I have taken reference from [enter link description here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

I have tried this piece of code

```
       createCookie('CityID', "", -1);
       document.cookie = "CityID=" + opt.attr('id');
       setCookie("CityID", DateTime.Now, 365);
```

but this doesnot works.
any idea to update the existing cookies. I am new to the concept of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Should get start with http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp to understand the basics of cookies. Also this will help you what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You just set the cookie and browser will update (or create if not exists) existing cookie.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name+ "=" +escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}
setCookie("cityid", "newid");
```